# Facebook LIKE buttons are popping out of my divs - CSS

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, facebook

I'm using Facebook like buttons on a website, they work perfectly.

**Unfortunately on IE8 the like buttons pop out of their container DIVs, dropping at the bottom of the page.**

---

example image:

[image]

---

#### This is after trying `display:block` as Kyle suggested:

[image]

---

**Any ideas? Would be really great. :)**

Comment: Why are you setting heights on the content areas of each offer? The last one on the first page  (Champneys) has the 'like' button ON the dotted line in Chrome. Removing the height attribute fixed it...

Comment: @josh.trow: desperation, thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source of that page, it appears to be a markup issue.

your `<fb:like>` tags must be closed.

So instead of :

```
<fb:like style="display:block;" ref="offer" href="URL" show_faces="false" layout="button_count" >
```

you should use

```
<fb:like style="display:block;" ref="offer" href="URL" show_faces="false" layout="button_count" />
```

On a side note, for more xHTML compatibility, you should also close all HTML tags, like

`<br />` instead of `<br>`

and

`<img alt='' src'' />` instead of `<img alt='' src=''>` etc..

Comment: Good catch on that, I missed it too! +1

Answer (score 2):

I *think* it's the display method `.fb_iframe_widget {display: inline-block}`. I believe that IE doesn't play nice with this attribute, try just inline or block.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for that! I posted a screen of what it looks like after the fix :) still not fixed unfortunately

Comment: I went through with IE8's developer tools (or what passes for it) and to be honest, I couldn't find a solution, can you post up your relevant CSS? Thanks :)

Comment: thanks for your help, I'll try and copy all the related CSS or try an reproduce the problem on another page :D